# C++ type punning with classes

Tags: c++, type-punning

I am writing some C++ code which wraps the std::unordered_map type, where I want to hide the underlying type and present it as another type. More specifically, I want to wrap the std::pair from the std::unordered_map with another type. For the sake of argument, lets suppose the wrapper looks like this...

```
template <typename ActualT >
class wrapper final
{
private:
    ActualT actual_;
public:
    //Some constructors...
    typename ActualT::first_type & get_first()
    {
        return actual_.first;
    }
    typename ActualT::second_type & get_second()
    {
        return actual_.second;
    }
};
```

My reasoning is that since the wrapper class only has a member which is the exact type which it is wrapping, converting a reference from the original type to the wrapper type should be fine, but the type compatibility for structs states that the members should have the same type and name for the types to be compatible. Would using type-punning in this fashion potentially cause undefined behaviour or alignment issues?

```
using my_map = std::unordered_map < int, int >;
my_map m;
//Do some inserts...
reinterpret_cast<wrapper<typename my_map::value_type>&>(*m.find(10)).get_second() = 1.0;
```

I want client code to be allowed to access the entries of a map without knowing about the pair which is returned by the map. I also want to write a custom forward iterator, hence I need to return a reference to the entry. Would converting the reference to the pair to a reference to a class which act as a wrapper be considered dangerous?

Is there perhaps a better approach to accomplishing this?

Comment: there are multiple things that doesn't look like c++ in this code

Comment: I have tried to remove all the HTML entity encoding from your code, but the reinterpret_cast line still looks wrong.  Can you fix it please.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I have changed the line.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap `my_map::value_type`? You can just use an alias of `my_map::reference`

Comment: From my understanding, using a class or a struct with a names that describe the usage is preferable, which in my opinion, the member variables of std::pair does not provide. I want to give the entries more meaningful names. I could for instance name the member function "key" and "value".

Comment: I'd write free functions like `my_map::key_type & MeaningfulNameHere(my_map::iterator)` (or `my_map::reference`) in that case

Comment: But I would like to access both they key and value type, such such that I could call the wrapper class something meaningful such as "entry".

Comment: You can wrap `value_type&` and pass around the wrapper by value. I would recommend leaving the standard library idioms alone though. People already understand them. There's nothing wrong with exposing them in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This absolutely is undefined behaviour.

Seriously rethink your priorities.

Some free functions of the form

```
const my_map::key_type & MeaningfulNameHere(my_map::reference)
```

will go a long way to giving you meaningful names.

If you *must* wrap the standard library with different names, just use a non-explicit constructor, and store references.

```
template <typename Map>
class entry final
{
private:
    typename Map::reference ref;
public:
    entry(Map::reference ref) : ref(ref) {}

    const typename Map::key_type & key()
    {
        return ref.first;
    }
    typename Map::mapped_type & value()
    {
        return ref.second;
    }
};
```

If you *really need* the iterator to dereference to `entry` you can. But you can just implicitly instantiate `entry`s from the `Map::reference`s returned by `Map::iterator::operator*`, you don't need a custom iterator.

```
template <typename Map>
class entry_iterator
{
private:
    typename Map::iterator it;
    entry<Map> entry;
public:
    entry<Map>& operator*() { return entry; }
    entry_iterator operator++() { ++it; entry = *it; return *this; }
    // etc
}
```

Comment: But a forward iterator must return a reference when dereferenced, hence I don't believe that it would be viable for a custom forward iterator.

Comment: +1 for mentioning UB right away. It’s more or less safe to assume that type punning like that is simply not allowed in C++.

Comment: Does the wrapper and the wrappee having the same size and layout suggest that the types are compatible?

Answer (score 2):

So you *could* clean this up, but I wouldn't suggest it:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Key, class Value>
class wrapper
{
public:
   explicit wrapper(std::pair<const Key, Value>& kvp)
      : _key{kvp.first}
      , _value{kvp.second}
   {}

   const Key& key() const { return _key; }
   Value& value()         { return _value; }

private:
   const Key& _key;
   Value& _value;
};

int main()
{
   unordered_map<int,int> m;

   m[1] = 1;
   m[3] = 3;

   auto it = m.find(1);

   wrapper w{*it};
   w.value() = 30;

   std::cout << w.key() << " -> " << w.value() << '\n';
}
```

The above effectively hides the `pair` from users of your class.  It doesn't deal with exceptions (`find()` returning `end()` for example), and makes no guarantees about lifetimes.  It's marginally better than what you have because it doesn't require a `reinterpret_cast` to an unrelated type.

However, `map`, `unordered_map`, `set`, etc. storing returning iterators as pairs is just part of library -- it's the canonical form and I don't see the benefit of shielding people from it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am not asking about the details of find, all code presented have just been there for demonstration. The issue is to do with converting a reference from the pair to the reference of the wrapper containing the pair, and if such a conversion would be prone to undefined behaviour due to type compatibility. I still appreciate the answer.